# Converting a String to Multiple objects (javascript)

Tags: javascript, json

I have the following string: `Jack:13,Phil:15,Lucy:12`I'm trying to fetch objects from this string.

This string would have 3 people objects with their ages. How can this be achieved?

I've tried the following:

```
var s = 'Jack:13,Phil:15,Lucy:12'

var obj1 = eval("("+s+")");
var obj2 = JSON.parse(s);
```

Logging any of the obj variables returns errors. Am I missing a simple trick here? Any explanation would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: 5 answers yet no one explains how it works and why not use `eval`. That is what OP needs, besides simply posting the solution..

Comment: @Adelin - I did start out saying something, then figured...meh. But you're right, I'll add it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, if you're doing replaces on a string to turn it into something you can pass `eval` or `JSON.parse`, that's probably not your best approach. An in particular, avoid using `eval` (or its cousin `new Function`) when you can (you certainly can here), and **always** avoid `eval` (or its cousin `new Function`) with untrusted input.

A pair of `split`s with `map` does it:

```js
const s = 'Jack:13,Phil:15,Lucy:12'
const people = s.split(",")
  .map(e => e.split(":"))
  .map(([name, age]) => ({name, age}));
console.log(people);
```

...or in ES5:

```js
var s = 'Jack:13,Phil:15,Lucy:12'
var people = s.split(",")
  .map(function(e) { return e.split(":"); })
  .map(function(e) { return {name: e[0], age: e[1]}; });
console.log(people);
```

I'm not sure why I did two maps rather than just doing the second split and creating the object in the same callback; I guess I'm thinking more and more in a "functional programming" way. I'd change it, but [Eddie's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50872508/157247) already does it in a single `map`, so...

...(edit) but since it looks like you wanted separate properties rather than using the person's name like Eddie did, here's an example of the above but with just a single `map`:

```js
const s = 'Jack:13,Phil:15,Lucy:12'
const people = s.split(",")
  .map(e => {
    const [name, age] = e.split(":");
    return {name, age};
  });
console.log(people);
```

...or in ES5:

```js
var s = 'Jack:13,Phil:15,Lucy:12'
var people = s.split(",")
  .map(function(e) {
    var parts = e.split(":");
    return {name: parts[0], age: parts[1]};
  });
console.log(people);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can `split()` the string and use `map()` to loop thru the array. This will return an array of objects.

```js
var s = 'Jack:13,Phil:15,Lucy:12';

var result = s.split(',').map(o => {
  let [k, v] = o.split(':');
  return {[k]: v};
});

console.log(result);
```

---

If you want a single object, you can use `reduce`

```js
var s = 'Jack:13,Phil:15,Lucy:12';

var result = s.split(',').reduce((c, o) => {
  let [k, v] = o.split(':');
  return Object.assign(c, {[k]: v});
}, {});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try with:

```
const result = s.split(',')
  .map(value => value.split(':'))
  .reduce((acc, [name, value]) => {
    acc[name] = +value;
    return acc;
  }, {});
```

Output:

```
{
  "Jack": 13,
  "Phil": 15,
  "Lucy": 12
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As I'm sure you've worked out there are many ways to do this, I thought I'd add another method

```js
let s = 'Jack:13,Phil:15,Lucy:12'
let obj = {};

s.split(",").forEach(part => {
  obj[part.split(":")[0]] = part.split(":")[1];
})
console.log(obj);
```

This is a simple split the string and then on each item of the new array do a split and push the results into an empty object already declared.

Answer (score 1):

You could split the parts and build a new object with key/value pairs.

```js
var string = 'Jack:13,Phil:15,Lucy:12',
    result = Object.assign(...string
        .split(',')
        .map(s => (([k, v]) => ({ [k]: v }))(s.split(':')))
    );
        
console.log(result);
```

For getting an array with objects

```js
var string = 'Jack:13,Phil:15,Lucy:12',
    result = string
        .split(',')
        .map(s => (([name, age]) => ({ name, age }))(s.split(':')));
        
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Easy to do with `.map()`:

```js
var s = 'Jack:13,Phil:15,Lucy:12';
var items = s.split(',')
    .map((entry) => entry.split(':'))
    .map((item) => ({name: item[0], age: item[1]}));

console.log(items);
```